# Find a sequence $a_n$ such that $X_{(n)} - a_n$ converges in distribution, where $X_{(n)} = \max(X_i), i=1:n$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be iid and exponential(1). Define $X_{(n)} = \max(X_i), i=1:n$. What is a sequence $a_n$ such that $X_{(n)} - a_n$ converges in distribution?

I think it would also converge to exponential distribution too, right?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** we can compute the cumulative distribution function of $X_{(n)}-a_n$, namely, $(1-e^{-(t+a_n)})\chi_{\mathbb R_+}(t+a_n)$. Can you find $a_n$ such that this quantity converges pointwise?